# Flutter: How Add Data into StreamController

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, future, stream-builder

I am making a ***pagination system*** for my ***Chat Application***. I want to consume as fewer reads as possible.

I am fetching the first 20 results with a ***Stream in StreamBuilder***, and I am fetching the next load or Load More (data) with ***future***: So that the data wouldn't get removed while the user is scrolling through, if the other user decides to delete the message.

Everything's working just fine but when I'm trying to ***pass the Next Batch data*** into ***the stream*** the whole list gets updated and the existing Streamed data gets replaced with the newly added data.

***First Query Results*** This is the list of data I have gotten with Stream Streambuilder and it's working absolutely fine. But Later on, the Next Batch or Load More Data replaces it all instead of just being added to it.
[image: The Result of initial or First Query. When user opens the screen these are the latest 20 entries he/she will be seeing]

***Second Query Results*** This should've been added to the existing data list, rather, it replaces all the current data.

The Message list should have 30 entries after the Fetch More Function is called, but it gets replaced with the newly fetched data and just have 10 entries, whereas, it had 20 earlier ***(First Query)***

[image: Second Query or Next batch of Data which should have been added to the list with other data (First Query), but it replaces it completely.]

***Whole File Codes***

```
class _PaginationPageState extends State<PaginationPage> {

  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _messagesStream;

  StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>> _streamController = StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>>.broadcast();
  List<DocumentSnapshot> _products = [];
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    if(mounted) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Hangout").doc("Chats").collection("Personal").doc("16970e27-4ee6-4678-968d-ac4dc20f409d").collection("Messages").limit(20).orderBy("sentDate".split("_KLisYaNeWDAy_").first, descending: true).snapshots().listen((event) {
        _streamController.add(event.docs);
      });
      _scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  var lastDoc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Pagination"),
    ),
      body: Container(
        height: (size.height * 1),
        width: (size.width * 1),
        child: StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
          // stream: _messagesStream,
          stream: _streamController.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData) {

              lastDoc = snapshot.data!.last;

              return ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Center(child: Text("${index + 1}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.black,),),),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Container(
                          width: (size.width * 1) - 80,
                          child: Text("${snapshot.data![index]["message"]}", overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, softWrap: true, maxLines: 2,),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Error Occured or Something!"),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  bool _hasNext = true;
  bool _isFetchingUsers = false;

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getUsers(var startAfter) async {
    print("Invoked Fetch Next Batch Get Data");
    try {
      final refUsers = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Hangout").doc("Chats").collection("Personal").doc("16970e27-4ee6-4678-968d-ac4dc20f409d").collection("Messages");
      if(startAfter! == null) {
        return _nully();

      } else {
        return refUsers.limit(10).orderBy("sentDate".split("_KLisYaNeWDAy_").first).startAfterDocument(startAfter).get();
        // return refUsers.limit(5).orderBy("sentDate".split("_KLisYaNeWDAy_").first, descending: true).startAfterDocument(startAfter).get();
      }

    } catch (e) {
      print("Error, Fetching Next Batch ${e}");
      return _nully();
    }
  }

  _nully() {
    print("Nully");
  }

  Future<void> fetchNextUser(var lasty) async {
    print("Invoked Fetch Next Batch Start");
    if(_isFetchingUsers) return;
    _isFetchingUsers = true;

    try{
      print("Invoked Fetch Next Batch Start 2.0.0");
      final snap = await getUsers(lasty);
      List<DocumentSnapshot> _messagesList1 = [];
      _messagesList1.addAll(snap.docs);
      print("Stream Before:  ${_streamController.stream.length}");
      _streamController.sink.add(_messagesList1);
      print("Length : ${_messagesList1.length} : ${_streamController.stream.length}");

      if(snap.docs.length < 10) {
        _hasNext = false;
        print("No More Data");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Fetch More : \n ${e}");
    }

    _isFetchingUsers = false;
  }

  void scrollListener() async {
    if(mounted) {
      if (_scrollController.offset >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent && !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
        if(_hasNext) {
          print("Invoked : ${lastDoc}");
          fetchNextUser(lastDoc);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Any help would be much appreciated***
Thanks